# Eclipse Pulsar, JavaME, and Hello World

Tags: eclipse, java-me, midp

I tried to post this over on the Eclipse Pulsar site, but it doesn't seem to want to give me access, so I thought I would try over here.

All I'm trying to do create a basic "hello world" application to test on multiple mobile phones as a proof of concept.  I downloaded Eclipse Pulsar and the Samsung SDK (though I have this problem with any SDK) and I created a new MIDlet Project and ME MIDlet and selected the 'hello world' wizard and the resulting code produces these errors:

"the import org.eclipse cannot be resolved" on all of the imports.

I know I'm missing something basic, but I would have expected org.eclipse to already be on the build path.  I tried adding eswt-converged.jar as and external JAR to the Libraries on the build path which fixes the import errors, but this seems like a hack and causes other problems.

So my question is:  What step have I missed in creating the Project/MIDlet and is there a how-to online somewhere that gives examples on this stuff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a "new eSWT Midlet". eSWT is a new UI toolkit that is not supported by most SDKs. Try using one of the other templates, something like Splash Midlet Template should be simple enough.

Comment: That was exactly correct.  I guess this means that each phone SDK has it's own library for creating GUIs.  Looks like it could be a real pain to make a program that works on multiple phones.  Thanks for the input!